# Alternative to Gridster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, drag-and-drop, grid

I have used the [Gridster](http://gridster.net/) library for a project that uses a drag-and-drop multi-column grid. Sadly, Gridster only supports Internet Explorer 9+.
I need to find a similar simple-to-use library which lets me do the same using IE8, and if it possible also compatible with IE7, and IE6 too.

So,  is there any Gridster-like library out there for the old-IE's? I'm using jquery in this project, so a jquery-based library could be also great.

P.S. I've found one called [AnimaDrag](http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/animadrag/), but it's not as good as Gridster, and it's kind of bad.

Comment: Ran into this post while researching on gridster: Are you able to use gridster with the latest version of jQuery? (1.8.x). . . it seems like it stops working for anything higher than 1.7.2 - can you confirm?

Comment: No, I was not able. I started with v1.8.x but I had some issues with it. Now I'm using v1.7.2.

Comment: Same here, but the rest of my portal uses the latest jQuery and we kinda' want to shy away from using .noConflict, but that's what I'm resorting to for now. I am hoping gridster.net is frequently upgraded, posted on their GitHub as well..

Answer (score 20):

There are also Shapeshift : https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift

and Gridly : http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/

which are good alternatives to Gridster. (yet note that Gridly is for squared tiles only)

Edit :
Packery is also very interesting : http://packery.metafizzy.co/
. However it requires a commercial licence for commercial project otherwise :

> For non-commercial, personal, or open source projects and
>   applications, you may use Packery under the terms of the GPL v3
>   License.

Edit 2 : This one may also be useful : https://github.com/uberVU/grid

Answer (score 16):

You can give a try to Gridstack: https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js
It's an early version but based strictly on gridster and it is also responsive.

Comment: Still very active a year later and looking great. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

[N.B. I posted this answer on the github page for the project on a similar question someone had raised. So check there in case this answer was corrected! - https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/74]

I spent the past few days with a similar issue - although I only needed IE8 support (though it seems to work in IE7). The issue was the code is updating the page correctly but IE would not pick-up/evaluate the data-row & data-col changes while the mouse was moving. I tried several things from the solution above, through to using modernizr & similar libraries and finally trying to bind to the IE only 'propertychange' event with no success.

It seems to be an IE8 limitation that it won't re-evaluate an element that is using CSS Attributes while the mouse is down/moving. However, it does detect class and in-line changes (which is why you can drag the box around).

Therefore the only solution I could find with the time available was to add/remove a fake class in the code whenever the widgets should be updated using jQuery .toggle(). So I added it in the code when the preview and widgets were passed new data-col & data-row attributes. This forces IE8 to pick up the change and voila the preview works.

Now I am sure there is a (much) better solution besides not using IE8 and it doesn't guarantee IE8 compatibility but if you're stuck then you may find this helpful!

p.s. I only had to worry about IE8+, IE7 seemed to be okay when using modernizr and similar plugins. However haven't tried in IE6 but I doubt it would work.

[EDIT]

Following the comment below I've now uploaded to an example - although I couldn't get IE8 to play nice with JSFiddle. So the example of it working in IE8 is here instead :

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/707074webfiles/gridster/ie8test.html

I have included IE9.js which (mostly) adds the transparency effect for the preview in this instance.

The modified copy of the gridster.js file is here:

https://github.com/Grozzer/gridster.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.gridster.js

It does include a number of other changes related to the resizing of widgets. However if you only want then IE8 changes then I suppose the best answer is to search it for mention of ie8compat.

At the time of writing the line changes for ie8 are :

- 717 : Added IE8 compatibility option
- 2054 - 2056 : Added the .toggle option to the preview widget
- 2433 - 2435 : Added the .toggle option to any widgets moved up
- 2488 - 2490 : Added the .toggle option to any widgets moved down

Comment: Eh, I'm not entirely sure how your answer would help me. I mean, it's an informative answer but I actually don't know which changes you've made to make it work. A JSFiddle may be useful in these cases to show what you've done

Comment: You're quite right - sorry. I've taken a fork of the code and will update with the relevant changes tomorrow. I tried to add them from memory (bad idea) but got some strange behaviour. However if you look here (https://github.com/Grozzer/gridster.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.gridster.js) and search for ie8compat in the meantime you might have a better idea of what I mean. So hopefully I'll be more helpful tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

Those looking at this wanting something for react there's react-grid-layout which doesn't seem to be getting issues fixed much:

https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

or react-curator:

https://github.com/codetrove-development/react-curator

Comment: It's worth noting that questions asking for software/library/tutorial/docs recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, as they are a vector for spam answers. It's ideal not to answer these at all if you can.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, gridster supports Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.
 If you wish to support the older IE browsers (6+), why not build functionalities around [jQuery draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [jQuery droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I don't want to do.. I mean, gridster is already a complete full customizable drag-n-drop multi-column grid.
It's easy-to-use, and no need to get into a lot of programming. 
I was just wondering if there was a similar library for older versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a polyfill to simulate the data-set functions of gridster ?
http://www.orangesoda.net/jquery.dataset.html may be a good alternative.

Comment: Well..... I'm not sure I would use that alternative.. it seems "time-consuming" and a bit "not-that-easy" to do it.. if you know what I mean.

Comment: orangesoda.net seems to no longer exist.